# How to print to a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lisp type languages usually provide an abstraction which allows you to open a *string* as a file, and then print to it using any function which can normally print to a file.  When you close the string you can recuperate the string that was printed.

Does something like this exist for python?

It probably would like something like this:

```py
f = open_string_as_output()
f.write("hello")
if some_condition:
   f.write(" ")
g(f) # allow g to write to the sting if desired
f.close()
str = f.get_string()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a class called `StringIO`, which does what you described.

```
import io
string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write('Foo')
if some_condition:
    string_out.write('Bar')
string_out.getvalue()  # Could be 'Foo' or 'FooBar'
```

Comment: Nice trick, but it looks like you've lost the versatility of the print function (multiple positional arguments, named arguments, ...)

Answer (score 2):

the `io` module allows exactly that: use the versatility of the `print()` function with the flux redirected to a string.

```
from io import StringIO
output = StringIO()
print("Hello World!", file=output)
print(f"I have written so far this to my string: {output.getvalue()}", file=output)

result = output.getvalue()
print(result)
```

outputs:

```
Hello World!
I have written so far this to my string: Hello World!
```

You cannot overuse this technique. See this example:

```
from io import StringIO
    garbage = StringIO()
def foo(stuff, out_flux=None):
# a function that prints stuff but you need to mute from times to times
        result = stuff
        print(result, file=out_flux)

# normal use
foo(10) # prints 10

# muted use
foo(10, out_flux=garbage) # prints nothing
print(garbage) # prints whatever was collected so far
```

Answer (score 1):

There is somthing called a ***string stream*** which might help you.

```python
import io # the library for input and output 
       
words = ["PEPPERS", "SWEET", "BELL", "AMPIUS", "PKT" "$2.00"] 

str_strm = io.StringIO()
   
# `sep` is `separator`    
# `end` is `end of line`

print(*iter(words), sep="...", end="\r\n", file=str_strm)

final_result = str_strm.getvalue()

str_strm.close() # a close the string stream to avoid a memory leak
```

---

However, there are simpler ways to print to a string.

```python
def print2str(*args, sep=' ', end='\n') -> str:
    it = iter(str(arg) for arg in args) 
    result = sep.join(it) + end
    return result
```